# Printing to textbox from class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, user-interface

I am trying to get data from a class to a windows form, it just needs to be displayed on the form my final goal is to have it graphed but if it can be in the text box i can graph it.

the data i am trying to display in the textbox is located in the FFT_DataHandling.cs program.
The target form is Form1.cs
The Textbox name is textbox1

[image]

[image]

Comment: May I know whether the answer can solve your problem or not? If not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question (I do NOT recommend you do this):

1. Open your `Form1.cs` code file (right click it and click "view code"), and add a static variable of the type "Form1".
2. In the constructor, set that variable to the current instance.
3. Create a method to set the text of the textBox.

You'll end up with something like this in the `Form.cs` file:

```
namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static Form1? _form1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _form1 = this;
        }
        public void SetTextBox1(string text)
        {
            textBox1.Text = text;
        }

        /* Rest of your code here
            .
            .
            .
        */
    }
}
```

Then from the `FFT_DataHandling.cs` you could call it like this:

```
namespace NAMESPACE
{
    public class FFT_DataHandling
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            Form1._form1.SetTextBox1("Ola");
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I would recommend you to do is:

1. Put the data handling code inside a method inside the `FFT_DataHandling.cs` file and return the data handled as a string.
2. You can either set the `FFT_DataHandling.cs` class and it's methods as static, or instantiate (if you must) it in the `Form.cs` code file.
3. Call the method of the `FFT_DataHandling.cs` file from the `Form.cs` code file and, since it returns a string, you can access the textBox1 variable directly and set it's text as the returned value of the method you just called.

So you'd end up with something like this:

```
namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //In case you've set the FFT_DataHandling.cs class as static:
            string handledData = FFT_DataHandling.NAME_OF_YOUR_METHOD();

            // OR....
            // If you need to instantiate it for some reason
            FFT_DataHandling dataHandling = new FFT_DataHandling();
            string handledData = dataHandling.NAME_OF_YOUR_METHOD();

            //Now you just need to set the textBox text:
            textBox1.Text = handledData;
        }
    }
}
```

Ps: Ideally you do not want several different classes/files altering a single form, this can lead to a very messy solution and hard to debbug later on... So it's better to put all code that alters the form inside the same form file, and call the external classes and it's functions from the form file.